# Summation of ${3^k}{k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am stucked on this question and have no idea. Can somebody tell me how to solve this summation?

$\Sigma ^n_{k=1} 3^kk^2$

Comment: We need to know what you already know. For starters, do you know how to do $\sum^n_{k=1} 3^k$?

Comment: Do you know any basic differentiation?

Comment: Yes, I know basics and summation of $3^k$.

Comment: You can lots of ideas for this sort of summation from the answers to this very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732

Comment: By the way, you can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: *Hint*. 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^nx^k\right)
$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Alternative to @Gonçalo's hint: try the Ansatz $(An^2+Bn+C)3^n+Dn^2+En+F$. You can get all but one of the coefficients from the change under $n\mapsto n-1$.